# MMQGIS is getting exponentially slower

Tags: geocoding, mmqgis

I'm trying to geocode about 250k addresses and after.  Several crashes later I split the file into several smaller files.  I even created a test file of 4 known addresses to check if it's functioning properly.

First run of the test file was near instant.  Followed by some successful and some unsuccessful runs of files with somewhere between 3000 and 50000 addresses.

I noticed it seems to be getting much slower.  So a reran the test file of 4 addresses and it took about 5 hours.  The last file I ran was about 3000 addresses and took about 30 hours.

I've tried uninstalling(which was it's own challenge as there's no standard uninstall function btw) and reinstalling the software to get the initial speed but that didn't work.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you using MMQGIS inside QGIS or as a standalone library? If it is QGIS which version? Which Web Service provider are you using for geocoding? Why do not you want to geocode your addresses outside of QGIS for instance with ArcPy since you have around 250.000 points?

Comment: I'm using it through QGIS version 3.12.3.  Most of the file that ran without issue were using US Census, but I have gotten Google to run successfully.  It was my understanding that ArcMap has moved to a pay as you go type geocoding service.  At the moment,  I'm just testing the viability of using geocoding as a solution.